# How to detect if push notifications are blocked on current website?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, onesignal

I am using OneSignal and want to be able to detect current subscribtion state between those three:

- user is blocking notifications
- not subscribed
- subscribed

OneSignal API gives the `isPushNotificationsEnabled` function, but it only detects two states: pushes allowed or not.

I wonder if there's more general (outside of OneSignal API) method to detect that, at least in some browsers.

Comment: Try reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API

Comment: And this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API

Comment: @KevinJantzer Thanks! I found that I can figure that out with Notification.permission, at least in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution turned out to be `Notification.permission`, which takes three states:

- default
- granted
- denied

And that's exactly what I needed.